# Prove $X_n$ fullfills Weak Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Use following facts:

- $\forall_{\epsilon>0} \mathbb{P}(X \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}X}{\epsilon}$ (Chebyshev's inequality)
- When $\lim_n n \mathbb{P}(|X| > n) =0$ and $X_n^* = X \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n\}}$ then $\lim_n \frac{\mathrm{Var(X_n^*)}}{n} = 0$ (proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521925/prove-lim-n-to-infty-frac-mathrmvarx-nn-0))

to prove:

Suppose $\lim_n n \mathbb{P}(|X| > n) =0$ and $X_n$ are i.i.d. with same distribution as X. Prove that $\{X_n\}$ fullfills the Weak Law of Large Numbers by showing:
$$
\lim_n \frac{S_n - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n} \to 0 \text { in probability }
$$
where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$.

So far I have found out:

- $0 = \lim_n n \mathbb{P}(|X|\geq n) \leq \mathbb{E}X$ but that gives me nothing useful
- If we define  $X_n^* = X \mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n\}}$ then
  $$
  \lim_n \frac{S_n - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n} = \frac{S_n - n\mathbb{E}X_n^*}{n} \geq \frac{S_n - n\cdot n\mathbb{P}(|X| \leq n)}{n} = \frac{S_n - n^2}{n}
  $$
  which is also rather pointless.

I appreciate any hints or solutions.

Comment: Why do not you look at the cited Feller's book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
& \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right| \geq  \varepsilon\right)\cr  & =  \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n^* - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon, |X_1|\leq n,\ldots, |X_n|\leq n\right) \cr & + \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon, |X_i|> n \text{ for some } i=1,\ldots, n\right) \cr
& \leq  \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n^* - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon\right)+n\mathbb P\left(|X_1|> n\right). 
\end{split}\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
The second term tends to zero. Consider the first term and apply Chebyshev's inequality. 
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n^* - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon\right) \leq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i^*)}{n^2\varepsilon^2} = \frac{\text{Var}(X_1^*)}{n\varepsilon^2} \to 0.
$$

Note also, that you are proved WLLN in the conditions that expectation $\mathbb EX$ need not to exist. The only thing that is given to you is the condition $n\mathbb P(|X| >n)\to 0$, which is more weak condition than $\mathbb E|X|<\infty$.

The hint to use Chebyshev's inequality did not mean that expectation exists. This is just a tool that can be applied in this problem to those random variables that have a expectation.

**Addition:**
The inequality in (1) follows from the inequality $\mathbb P(A\cap B)\leq \mathbb P(A)$ (as well as $\mathbb P(B)$). So 
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n^* - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon, |X_1|\leq n,\ldots, |X_n|\leq n\right)\leq \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n^* - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon\right)
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon, |X_i|> n \text{ for some } i=1,\ldots, n\right)
$$
$$\leq \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n\{|X_i|> n\}\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n P\left(|X_i|> n\right)=n\mathbb P(|X_1|>n).
$$

Comment: Do I understand it right - you have denoted $S_n^*$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \mathbb{1}_{\{|X_i| \leq n\}}$?

Comment: Yes, sure, it is a sum of truncated r.v.'s.

Comment: Hopefully last question - why does the inequality hold here: $
\mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n^* - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon, |X_1|\leq n,\ldots, |X_n|\leq n\right)+\mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon, |X_i|> n \text{ for some } i=1,\ldots, n\right) 
\leq  \mathbb P\left(\left| \frac{S_n^* - n\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq n \}}}{n}\right|\geq \varepsilon\right)+n\mathbb P\left(|X_1|> n\right). 
$

Comment: Since $P(A\cap B) \leq P(A)$. In the first probability we remove the event $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{ |X_i|\leq n\}$, in the second probability we remove the event $|\frac{S_n -...}{n}|\geq \varepsilon$. Next, $P(\bigcup\{|X_i|>n\})\leq \sum P(|X_i|>n)=nP(|X_1|>n)$.

Comment: @math_beginner Look at the added text to the answer.

Comment: Now it is crystal clear! Thank you for such detailed answers today.

Comment: You are welcome!